# Need to add an additional option in a select, when in edit mode, preselect it and remove a required class

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a form. It is in either edit (fields will be populated when opened) or add (not populated). I have a select with options displayed from a database. I need to add an additional option for the user to select that is not included in the database. If the form is in edit mode, and that option ('Not Specified') is selected, I then need to populate the select with it and remove the required class on the element.

My current code will populate the select for a user to choose from with 'Non Specified' and if I am in edit mode it will populate the value correctly, however I can't seem to get the required class to remove (when something required is filled in, the element will turn green, with this code, it stays red).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

```
<cf_FormGroupTag elementType="select" elementName="sampling_event" elementId="sampling_event" mainLabel="Sampling Event:" mainLabelWidth="col-sm-4 col-md-3" elementDivClass="col-sm-8 col-md-9" inputClass="input-md required required-extend" query="SamplingEvent" optionDisplay="sampling_event" optionValue="sampling_event" selectedOptions="#sampling_event_value#" initialDisabledOption="yes" initialDisabledOptionDisplay="sampling event"/>

$('#sampling_event').append($('<option>', {value:'Not Specified', text:'Not Specified'}));
if (isNew === 'NO' && sampling_event_value === 'Not Specified') {
     $('#sampling_event').val('Not Specified').removeClass('required required-extend');
   }

Select from the page source. 'Not Specified is being show as the input value in my form, but it is not here as an option.
```

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="sampling_event" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-md-3">Sampling Event:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <select name="sampling_event"  id="sampling_event" class="input-md required required-extend">
         <option value="" selected disabled>--Select sampling event--</option> 
                <option value="Event 1">Event 1</option>
                <option value="Event 2">Event 2</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: The "Not Specified" option is being selected with that last line, correct? I tried some tests in jsfiddle and did not find a problem with your approach in latest version of jquery. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I realized I left out the tag and just added that.
Yes, in the last line, if the page is (not isNew), then I need 'Not Specified' to be 'selected'.

Version 3.3.1
Thanks!

Comment: Can you shown an example of the select tag output from the page source? Just to be clear, 3 things should be happening... 1) add Not Specified option to select 2) select Not Specified option 3) remove classes from select. Am I correct in understanding that 1 and 2 are currently happening correctly, but 3 is not?

Comment: Do you have any info on `<cf_formGroupTag>`

Comment: Thanks Dan! 

Sorry I got busy and am just now getting back to respond to this. Yes, so i looked in the console and it seems like even though the value is being selected it does not have the attr of 'selected'. I have tried .attr('selected', true) rather than removing the class which still didn't work.

Comment: Additionally, I added the information from the page source in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.change();` seems to trigger the event to `'select'` the added option.

```
$('#sampling_event').val('Not Specified').change();
```